# Ruby Array Elements

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create password Generate in ruby. At the moment all is working just got stuck at the final piece of generating the password.

I asked user if he/she would like the password to include numbers, lowercase or uppercase.
If YES,  user will enter 1 and 0 for NO.

I used the code below to generate password if everything is 1. Meaning user want to include numbers, lowercase and uppercase.

```
 if numbers == 1 && lowercase == 1 && uppercase == 1
     passGen = [(0..9).to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a + ('a'..'z').to_a].flatten.sample(10)
 end

 p passGen
```

This works 90% of the time. 10% of the time the generated password will not include say any numbers. But everything else present. I am not sure if this is because of the size or length of Array from which the password is sampled.

Anyway lets go to the main problem below

Here is the problem,  I am struggling to write the code to generate password if one or more of input is 0. That's if user don't want to include numbers. Or no numbers and uppercase  etc . As I can't predict what user may want or not want. I need help on this please.
Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using a version of Rails that hasn't been maintained in years and has multiple unpatched security vulnerabilities? And what does this have to do with Rails anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't know it needs to include a digit/letter from every group. The sample takes random signs and since you a basically sampling `0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` there is a possibility that all the signs will not be digits.

The easiest way to fix it is to check if a sign from every group is in the "password" and then replace a random sign with a sign from group that is not present.

If I were to program this I would do it like that

```
def random_from_range(range)
    range.to_a.sample.to_s
end

def passGen(numbers, lowercase, uppercase)
    result = ''
    possibleSigns = []
    if numbers == 1
        range = (0..9)
        result += random_from_range(range)
        possibleSigns += range.to_a
    end
    if lowercase == 1
        range = ('A'..'Z')
        result += random_from_range(range)
        possibleSigns += range.to_a
    end
    if uppercase == 1
        range = ('a'..'z')
        result += random_from_range(range)
        possibleSigns += range.to_a
    end
    desired_lenth = 10
    while result.length < desired_lenth
        result += possibleSigns.sample.to_s
    end
    result
end

puts passGen(1,1,1)
```

Comment: Please read the whole question - the actual question is in the last paragraph: `I am struggling to write the code to generate password if one or more of input is 0.`

Comment: yes, yes, Ik, edited to include my answer

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution answered both questions. Thank

Comment: Minor: `sample(1)[0]` is just `sample`

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make your input array more dynamic:

```
passGen = []
passGen += (0..9).to_a if numbers == 1
passGen += ('A'..'Z').to_a if uppercase == 1
passGen += ('a'..'z').to_a if lowercase == 1
passGen.sample(10).join
```

Now, to tackle your other issue with missing characters - this is caused as you are simply taking 10 random characters from an array. So it can just take, for example, all digits.

To tackle this you need to get one character from each generator first and then generate the remaining characters randomly and shuffle the result:

```
def generators(numbers:, lowercase:, uppercase:)
  [
    (0..9 if numbers),
    ('A'..'Z' if uppercase),
    ('a'..'z' if lowercase)
  ].compact.map(&:to_a)
end

def generate_password(generators:, length:, min_per_generator: 1)
  chars = generators.flat_map {|g| Array.new(min_per_generator) { g.sample }}
  chars += Array.new(length - chars.length) { generators.sample.sample }
  chars.shuffle.join
end

gens = generators(numbers: numbers == 1, uppercase == 1, lowercase: lowercase == 1)
Array.new(10) { generate_password(generators: gens, length: 10) }
```

Comment: It doesn't address the issue in question, pls read what he asks about

Comment: This will provoke the same issue

Comment: @Vulwsztyn The main issue is: `I am struggling to write the code to generate password if one or more of input is 0. That's if user don't want to include numbers.` Please read the whole question.

Comment: thanks for your input. your solution thus solved the first problem.

Comment: @Homer - Updated answer with a bit more generic solution to both issues.

Comment: @BroiSatse - Very good solution. Thank you.  Worked perfect for both problems. I only changed the value in the new array to 1, as it returned 10 passwords.  Also the gens line was missing "uppercase:" symbol. After making these changes everything working 100%.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By saying `(0..9).to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a + ('a'..'z').to_a`, you're creating an Array of 10 + 26 + 26 = 62 elements, and then you pick only 10 elements out of it.

At your place I'd wrap password generation around an `until` block:

```rb
def generate_password_with_digits_and_caps
  [(0..9).to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a + ('a'..'z').to_a].flatten.sample(10).join
end


passGen = ''
until passGen.match(/[A-Z]/) && passGen.match(/[a-z]/) && passGen.match(/\d/)
  passGen = generate_password_with_digits_and_caps
end
```

This could also work (closer to your snipppet):

```rb
if numbers == 1 && lowercase == 1 && uppercase == 1
  passGen = ''
     
  until passGen.match(/[A-Z]/) && passGen.match(/[a-z]/) && passGen.match(/\d/)
    passGen = [(0..9).to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a + ('a'..'z').to_a].flatten.sample(10).join
  end
end
```

Comment: Please read the whole question - the actual question is in the last paragraph: `I am struggling to write the code to generate password if one or more of input is 0.`

Comment: I've shared an idea which may not be the best but rather simple to implement

Comment: Thanks for your input, extremely useful. This solves the first part of the question.  I just didn't know there were many ways of approaching this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Start with something simple and stupid:

```
passGen = (('0'..'9').to_a.sample(1)+ ('A'..'Z').to_a.sample(1)+('a'..'z').to_a.sample(8).shuffle).join
```

Technically speaking, this already fulfills your requirement. From the viewpoint of aesthetics and security, the disadvantage here is that the number of upper case characters is always 8. A more elegant solution would be to find three non-zero integers which add up to 10, and can be used as the arguments for the `sample` call. Also, if no numbers are requested, you simply pass `0` as argument to `sample`.

Since this exceeds the scope of your question, and I don't even know whether you want to go so far, I don't elaborate on this here further.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. The length of the password would be set by user, I gave 10 for simplicity’s sake. Finding three non-zero integer that adds up to an unknow length may not be easy approach for a novice. Also, I am not sure if the "shuffle" in your code is working well as the output starts with a number and capital letter, same way as the position for the numbers and capital in the code. I don’t see it shuffling. Forgive me if I am wrong.

Comment: To add to this - splitting a number into few parts was my first approach as well, but it is much more complicated than it appears to be, especially if you want to maintain equal probabilities of such splits. For example, splitting 10 into 3 parts: If you naivly just start by taking a random number from 1 to 8, then you have a little bit over 1/8 probability of getting [8, 1, 1] split and only 1/15 to get [4,3,3] (in any order).

Comment: This is correct, but you did not specify anything in your question. You also did not specify what properties (equal probabilities etc.) the desired numbers should have. At least spliting the total number into suitable random batches of numbers is a problem on its own, and if you want to discuss this, you should open a new question anyway. In Stackoverflow, the policiy is that one question should focus on a single problem.